# multiple threads writing to one server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem. I want to create a network connection so that I can make a multiplayer game. I know and understand sockets.
My problem is that if I press two keys on the keyboard at the same time it writes to the socket at the same time which causes an error. What I then did was create multiple sockets for one client to writ to and only writes to a socket that isn't busy. By for some reason seems to overload it or something. Any ideas for simultaneously sending messages to server and vice versa.

Comment: You should have a queue that the `Socket` reads from and then writes out.  You keep adding to the queue allowing the `Socket` to write each item as fast as it can.  A blocking queue of some kind would probably be suitable

Comment: Please have a look @ Java NIO Socket programming. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/nio/channels/selector-channels/java-nio-channels-selector-example/ There are many abstracted open source servers too.

Comment: Queueing was my problem, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code doing like this in server?

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }
        // new threa for a client
        new MyThread(socket).start();
    }
```

then, inside MyThread#run

```
    inp = socket.getInputStream();
    brinp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
    out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    line = brinp.readLine(); // read the data.
    out.writeBytes(line + "\n\r"); //write back to client
    out.flush(); // flush socket
```

Java NIO would faster and efficient. Please refer open source netty servers as well.

Comment: Sorry, placed in wrong place.                                                                              That might be the problem,to recieve input i have a threadloop that reads input 1000 a second, which is slower than a while loop but it reduces proccessing power.

Comment: threadloop ?? Could you please explain more? Always better to post code as well. You can hide biz logic.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it, there was a problem with my keyboard adapter , it was freezing. A Threadloop is an object i created sorry, its a timer task basicaly that runs a method until it is called to stop. See Timer. So I use a timertask instead of a while loop because if a while loop runs constantly it takes up 50% of the cpu. If I have 2 while loops running, it freezes my pc aswell. So the fastest a timertask can run a method is 1000 times a millisecond. thus a lot slower than a while loop but it doesnt take up more than 1% cpu..

Comment: I dont use any while loops that have the ability to run endlessly because they use up a lot of cpu. The only threads I use are within the Timer class that initiates a task every interval.

Comment: with small tiny sleep you can use loops. say sleep(100); It wont ate all CPU.

Comment: Look into Java NIO and TCP sockets... Netty server is really fast as it can handle 15K connection ... may be connection every second. Reactor server are widely used in game industry. Google Java NIO or java netty or java reactor

Comment: Thanx.. sleep is just a delay from what i know? Which is what i  using.

Comment: bobs_007 That is technically what I have used. I have created a timertask that is set to every millisecond, and runs a specified method. it is similar to making a thread sleep, but I do not use threads because they don't function in the way I would like. a timerTask can run asynchronously and with threads , im not sure how to explain why i do not use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a queueing method and has fixed the problem.