# Mulitple clients with a server and sockets?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, client, server

I am making a server client system which will need to be able to accept multiple clients.  One class will handle accepting data and another sends it back.  But how do I get it so that the server sends the data back to the correct client?

The part that receives information looks as such:

```
try {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            recieveType = inFromClient.readLine(); //reads the recieveType, packet or other
            packetID = inFromClient.readLine(); //reads the packet ID
            packetData1 = inFromClient.readLine(); //reads first line of packet data
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But how to I take the clients data, modify it, and then send it back to the correct client?

Comment: accept should be in while loop and start thread (from threadPool).... then sleep say 100 or something and again listen on accept... in tread#run read data from stream and write back to client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431519/multiple-threads-writing-to-one-server/30431734#30431734